# How to modify imported files in python

Tags: python, import, module, binance

I'm slowly despairing of Python import module
-Cloned binance_f from github and installed with setup.py. 
-Modification in files don't show up --> I searched and found:

```
import importlib
importlib.reload(module)
```

Then I get an error message:

```
> importlib.reload(binance_f)
> NameError: name 'binance_f' is not defined
```

The problem might be the "from" statement:

```
from binance_f import RequestClient
from binance_f.model import *
from binance_f.constant.test import *
from binance_f.base.printobject import *

import importlib
importlib.reload(binance_f)
```

If I don't execute the setup.py I get the follwoing error:

```
> from binance_f import RequestClient
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'binance_f'
```

How can that issue be resolved? Is there any way to "globally" reload other modules? I mean, what are you doing if you clone a github repository but can not change the files?

Best regards

Comment: I think that in order to reload a module you need to have an explicit import: `import <module>; reload(<module>)`

Comment: @pciunkiewicz do you mean something like that:

`import binance_f
import binance_f.requestclient
from binance_f import RequestClient
from binance_f.model import *
from binance_f.constant.test import *
from binance_f.base.printobject import *

import importlib
importlib.reload(binance_f)
importlib.reload(binance_f.requestclient)`

It still takes the cached version and don't update the requestclient module